# Webdriver: Firefox profile for disable/enable javascript popup dynamically

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, firefox, webdriver

I am writing a test case where I have to close a java script popup. My code works fine in windows but I am deploying the executable in a centOS based server where it is getting error like below:

```
Element is not clickable at point (719, 9.899993896484375). Other element     would receive the click: <li style="display: block; bottom: 0px;"
```

Can someone tell me what might be the problem?

I also tried the following but it does not work.

```
FirefoxProfile p = new FirefoxProfile();
p.setPreference("browser.popups.showPopupBlocker", false);
p.setPreference("browser.history.allowPopState", false);
p.setPreference("privacy.popups.showBrowserMessage", false);
p.setPreference("privacy.popups.usecustom", false);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(p);
```

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem.
Instead of clicking the close button of the JS popup, I removed the popup by executing javascript by injection.

```
JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jsExecutor.executeScript("return document.getElementsByClassName('dateInfo')[0].remove()");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use to click using `JavascriptExecutor` :-

```
WebElement element = "Your Element";
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element );
```

Hope it will help you :)